# commenting out a single word from a line

Tags: pdftex, function

I have not got any solution after a few try. In latex, how we can comment out a single word from a line. I mean for example

```
Hello %this is so on
```

it comments out *this* and the rest of the line as well. Is there any way to comment out only *this* part, not the rest of the line ?

Comment: just, at the end of the line. Press the enter button to go to another line.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, no.

But in LaTeX

```
Hello this is so on
```

is the same has

```
Hello this
is so on
```

So you can just do

```
Hello %this
is so on
```

You can use tricks to just remove part of a line, like

```
Hello \iffalse this\fi is so on
```

(Or several other things, [like using the `comment` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/comment?lang=en)), but that's overly complex.

Comment: you would be better  without the `{}` after `\fi` (get a double space as it is)

Comment: Ach, darn, I was thinking about changing it into a `\iftrue` later... as I said, overly complex.

Comment: You can also write a macro that gobbles its argument, e.g. `\newcommand{\mycomment}[1]{}`, and then write `Hello \mycomment{This is a comment} world`

Comment: Or use  `\sbox0{this }` (although the ghost of `this` will linger).